# Wordpress Subdomains with different content

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

im new to Wordpress, i searched the web but not finding any answer.
Now my problem.
1. I have a Website with a conten"www.mywebsite.de" --> "OnePager"
2. I have a mySql database with users.

I want to add a subdoamin like www.jon.mywebsite.de.
"Jon" is my user in the mySQL database!
The content have to be the same (main page). Except one section. In one section i want to show the data from the database. Somthing like Name, email, and Foto.

Is there a way to do that? Some ready modules?

Here's my code so far:

```
$db = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'paasword'); 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM USERS'; 
$result = mysql_db_query('db436654', $sql, $db); 
$arrUsers = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Edit:
I think i got somthing.
I created a custom page in my theme, in the admin section i select my template from the dropdown. BUT wordpress somehow pick the standard template!

Comment: have you looked into wordpress multi-site?

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to generate new sites, the site is always the same except one section/page

Comment: you can still do that with multisite. however if its just a small section then I'd load all the data and us javascript to show/hide the correct one based on url

Comment: ok, but how can i load the data? Where to start? Do i need a plugin or can i hack it into my onepager somehow?

Comment: No, its simple enough without a plugin. please show how you are currently loading the data

Comment: $db = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'paasword');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM USERS';
$result = mysql_db_query('db436654', $sql, $db);
$arrUsers = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); it is a simple db connect

Comment: i need to inject some php and html code in my onepager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finay i found i solution.
After several hours i found out that my OnePager is not accepting own Template for pages. So i have to change the strukture of the OnePage builder plugin and implement my own page with my custom code. Now it works :/

Thank you for you help.